# What is the purpose of the 'ssh_keys' group?

Tags: ssh, group

I was asked to add a user to the ssh_keys group, but could not find what the purpose of this group is, so I had to refuse it, but need to learn better. This is about RHEL 7

Answer (score 3):

In RHEL and Fedora, the `ssh_keys` group is the group owner of the host private SSH keys, used in `sshd` by the host to identify itself and encrypt the connection.

Unless an user has a very specific reason to get access to these keys, he should not be in that group.

Comment: Note taht in Fedora 38, the group was removed. The keys belong to `root` now. See https://www.spinics.net/lists/fedora-devel/msg307707.html and https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/openssh/pull-request/37#